# Resumable upload always returns 404

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get resumable upload working through the google drive v3 REST api. This feature isn't available in the java client SDK so I'm doing this using HttpClient calls. The gsuite service account that I'm using works fine with the java SDK to either create or update files. But I need to be able to upload larger files through the resumable API and it always returns 404 Not Found. The docs say this means the session is no longer valid but I have just created it when I make the call that returns 404 so it must be something else.

Here are the calls I'm making:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
Authorization: Bearer [AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{"mimeType":"text/csv","name":"TestSheet.csv","parents":["PARENT_FOLDER_ID"]}
```

This always works to create the session and I correctly get the Location: header out of the response and use that for subsequent calls. But when I go to write the first chunk of data, I do this:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=[UPLOAD_ID]
Content-Length: 1048576
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Range: bytes 0-1048575/3063739
[1048576 bytes of data]
```

And this always returns a 404 Not Found.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If you check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_app_with_id_appid_cannot_be_used_within_the_authenticated_users_domain), you need to do this `Suggested action: Report to the user that the domain does not allow your app to access files in Drive. Suggest that the user contact the domain admin to request access for your app`.

Comment: But using the exact same credentials, I can use the java SDK to write files without an issue. Are permissions for resumable uploads different from single uploads and updates? I don't see that in the docs.